# How can I create a history of previously created TextViews in an Android App? One that the user can access

Tags: android, logging, textview, record, history

I have a simple simple app, that simply takes a user's question as input, and creates a long string containing: the original question, and a randomly generated answer. This string then gets displayed as a TextView (I'm sorry if I'm not describing this correctly).

What I would like is to have a tab or page where instead of asking a question, I can see all the previous questions, and select one to see the same string that contained the Question and the Answer.

I don't even know how to phrase this to get useful results from searching. I'm really at a loss here, and anything would be a help.

Thanks!

Comment: There are couple of ways you can do this. I would recommend using database, even though it's not that easy to get a grasp of it. Another option is to save your data in JSON format and save it into let's say internal storage of your device. This might also be helpful to you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I have found a tutorial if that is what you are looking for. http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895, Also consider storing data on cloud if there are too many questions.

Comment: Thank you Jerry, very helpful link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your results in a database.http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Thank you! Ended up just writing it all to a text file. Which suits my purposes, but this link was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with the questions and answers as two columns, and keep saving each entry into that table in the database.
Note: Check whether or not you want to make the question as primary key, according to whether you want questions to have more than one random answers.